# Log4J: Backup file name with sysdate

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to name the backup file from log4j appending the sysdate into the name instead of filename.1, filename.2 ....

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need to use the Log4J "extras" JAR (provided by Apache), and use the `RollingFileAppender` found there (see the `FileNamePattern` parameter): http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/index.html

For example (taken from the Javadoc there):

```
<appender name="ROLL" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="/wombat/foo.%d{yyyy-MM}.gz"/>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

Comment: How I can configure that in log4j.properties??

Comment: Such "newer" configuration facilities are only available if you use XML to configure Log4J, using the `DOMConfigurator`. Basically, all you need to do is convert your `log4j.properties` file to XML format, call it `log4j.xml` and place it in your classpath. You can look at `DOMConfigurator` for further information. XML is the go-forward direction of Log4J configuration anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the files to be backed up at a certain frequency, such as at every minute or on an hourly basis, `DailyRollingFileAppender` class would suite your purpose.

However, if you need the files to be archived after they reach a certain size, perhaps one good approach would be to extend `RollingFileAppender` class. You need to override its `rollover()` method in a way similar to below:

```
public void rollOver() {
...

file = new File(fileName + '.' + System.currentTimeMillis());

...

}
```

Comment: That has already been done by the Log4J community (see my answer below).

Comment: I have a problem overriding rollOver() method. It access to a private attribute of RollingFileAppender not reacheable from extending class

Comment: @AlexCuervo Have you tried `setFile(fileName + '.' + System.currentTimeMillis())`?

Comment: @Isaac I think this implementation works for fixed rolling period only. OP needs something which rolls over after the file reaches the size limit but have `sysdate` instead of rolling index.

Comment: @Reza wrong. This works for any implementation of `RollingFileAppender`. The configuration separates between the rolling policy and the filename format. The snippet I provided below is only an example.